# Laravel 5.7 Fullcalendar - dayclick route with parameters

Tags: routes, fullcalendar, crud, materialize, laravel-5.7

I just try when I click on a day in Fullcalendar that I pass on a link with parameters (example route('reservation.create'). The parameter are "verhicle_id", "user_id" and date.

I have following code (reservationController):

```
public function booking($id) {
  $reservations = Reservation::where('vehicle_id', $id)->get();
  return view('reservations.index')->with('reservations', $reservations);
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
  <div class="section container">
    <h1>Calendar</h1>
    <div id="calendar" class="tooltipped"></div>
  </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')

var data = [
    @foreach($reservations as $reservation)
    {
        title : '{{ $reservation->vehicle->name }}',
        start : '{{ $reservation->start_date }}',
        description: '{{ $reservation->vehicle->location->name }} <br>Reservation from: {{ $reservation->user->name }}',
        color: '{{ $reservation->vehicle->color }}',
        url : '{{ route('reservations.edit', $reservation->id) }}'
    },
    @endforeach
];
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        events: data,
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                //here I want to link to CRUD reservations.create with parameter vehicle_id, user_id and date clicked
            },


        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.tooltip({
                position: 'top',
                html: event.title + "<br>" + event.description,
                trigger: 'hover'
            });
        }
    });

});
@endsection
```

But I have no information or access about vehicle_id and user_id in this code.
How would I have to customize the code that I receive this information.
I don´t want so make it in modal.

The reason why I want to do this is that the user no longer needs to specify this data in the create-form (are hidden-fields).

Sorry for my poor english. I hope everyone can help me.
Regards
Dimi

Comment: You could just use your PHP code to write that data into hidden fields in the page. Then when dayClick runs, get those values from the hidden fields and use them as parameters in your link to the form.

Answer (score 1):

@ADyson: Thanks for your comment.

I have a solution about my problem. It works for me fine. But it is a prototype for me.

reservationsController:

```
public function booking($id)
{
    $user_id = 2;
    $reservations = Reservation::where('vehicle_id', $id)->get();
    return view('reservations.index')->with(['reservations' => $reservations, 'vehicleid' => $id, 'userid' => $user_id]);
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $reservation = new Reservation;
    $reservation->user_id = $request->input('userid');
    $reservation->vehicle_id = $request->input('vehicleid');
    $reservation->budget_id = $request->input('budget');
    $reservation->start_date = $request->input('date');
    $reservation->end_date = $request->input('date');
    $reservation->save();
    return redirect()->route('reservations.booking', ['id' => $reservation->vehicle_id]);
}
```

index.blade.php (I worked with modal in materialize)

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="section container">
    <h1>Calendar</h1>
    <div id='calendar' class="tooltipped"></div>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <div id="modal1" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <h1>Create Reservation</h1>
        <form class="col s6" action="{{route('reservations.store')}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <select name="budget">
              <option value="1">Budget 1</option>
              <option value="2">Budget 2</option>
              <option value="3">Budget 3</option>
            </select>
            <label>Budget</label>
        </div>
          <input readonly value="" name="vehicleid" id="vehicleid" type="hidden">
          <input readonly value="" name="userid" id="userid" type="hidden">
          <input readonly value="" name="date" id="date" type="hidden">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
        </button>
    </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
    @section('scripts')

    var data = [
        @foreach($reservations as $reservation)
        {
            title : '{{ $reservation->vehicle->name }}',
            start : '{{ $reservation->start_date }}',
            description: '{{ $reservation->vehicle->location->name }} <br>Reserviert: {{ $reservation->user->name }} <br>Seats: {{ $reservation->vehicle->seats }} ',
            color: '{{ $reservation->vehicle->color }}',
            url : '{{ route('reservations.edit', $reservation->id) }}'
        },
        @endforeach
    ];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        @isset($vehicleid)
            var vehicleid = {{$vehicleid}};
        @endisset
        @isset($userid)
            var userid = {{$userid}};
        @endisset
        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
            events: data,
                dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
// above I filled the value in the form hidden fields
                    $('#vehicleid').val(vehicleid);
                    $('#userid').val(userid);
                    $('#date').val(date.format());
                    $('#modal1').modal('open');
                    $('.trigger-modal').modal();
                },


            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                element.tooltip({
                    position: 'top',
                    html: event.title + "<br>" + event.description,
                    trigger: 'hover'
                });
            }
        });

    });
@endsection
```

If anybody have a better solution please let me know.
Regards
Dimi